# What is the most elegant way to replace a Spring bean with a proxy?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am working with a Spring Boot starter, and as so, with many auto-configured beans.

In this starter, I'd like to create a proxy around one of the beans to add some "operations" around two methods.

I can't do it statically as what I define in this starter are `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`: a random implementation can be provided, but still, I need to wrap the calls so that my required "operations" are added.

So here is the question: what is the most elegant way to have both logics executed (the one in the bean defined by the starter user, along with my "operations")?

I'm thinking of post-processing the application context and replacing the provided bean with a proxy of my own but I don't quite know how or if there are better ways to go.

Comment: ootb spring provides some [AOP capabilities](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop.html) in order to support such desires, `Bean(Factory)PostProcessor` is actually a kind of last resort in spring application design, and we prefer to stay clear of it if possible.

Comment: I was a bit scared of complexity when it comes to build native image.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov I went the AOP way if you want to turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.